# Modify a single class within a pre-compiled jar?

Tags: java

I have a jar with no source, and would like to modify a single class file inside of it. However whenever i export a jar then extract the class to be placed back inside, it never works the same.

What are the proper steps to replacing a class within a jar? (i can see the class contents by viewing it with JDGUI)

Comment: This is not straightforward at all to pull off. You sure you can't get the source code or find a way to design around it?

Comment: I would like to make my own changes within it and i cannot find the source anywhere.

Comment: You might be able to try some weird bytecode reverse-engineering voodoo, but even then I don't know if the JRE will like that. And if the bytecode is obfuscated, you probably are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are modifying class signatures and are afraid that you are breaking something within the compiled code, then you should probably do the following:

Unzip the `.jar` and run a Java decompiler (e.g., Jad). Then you can modify the file you want to as much as you want. Rebuild everything and package it into a new `.jar` file.

Comment: The jar is huge and there are tons of libraries shaded in. I tried this and came across tons of decompilation errors.